# writeln em JavaScript está em desuso ou não?

Tags: javascript

Eu não achei nenhuma documentação falando que `writeln` está obsoleto, mas era para ele escrever em uma nova linha, mas não é o que está acontecendo, ele funciona igual o `write` e fica em uma linha só. Alguém sabe se ele ainda funciona nas especificações do ECMAScript 2018?

```js
// Usando write
document.write("Mesma Linha1");
document.write("Mesma Linha2");

// Quebra de linha
document.write("<br/>");

// Usando o writeln
document.writeln("Nova Linha1");
document.writeln("Nova Linha2");
```

Answer (score 2):

Olhando o material da especificação [ECMAScript 2018](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#Title) não se encontra referência da função, porém na documentação do [WHATWG.org](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dynamic-markup-insertion.html#document.writeln()) a função continua ativa. Acredito que esteja em desuso, pois com tantos recursos mais avançados surgidos desde a especificação em que o `.writeln` foi implementado ([DOM Level 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/), há cerca de 16 anos), ele se tornou obsoleto e sem muita (ou nenhuma) utilidade.

A função `document.writeln` insere uma quebra de linha `\n` no final da string. Como o HTML trata quebra de linha no código como um espaço, você irá visualizar um texto após o outro separados por um espaço:

```js
document.writeln("texto1");
document.writeln("texto2");
```

No entanto, se você colocá-lo dentro de uma tag `<pre>` a quebra de linha é aplicada, pois o conteúdo da tag `<pre>` é renderizada no navegador como está no código-fonte:

```js
document.write("<pre>");
document.writeln("Nova Linha1");
document.writeln("Nova Linha2");
document.write("</pre>");
```

Fazendo um replace nos `\n` adicionado pelo `.writeln` por `<br>` para quebrar a linha no HTML:

```js
// Usando write
document.write("Mesma Linha1");
document.write("Mesma Linha2");

// Quebra de linha
document.write("<br/>");

// Usando o writeln
document.write("<div>");
document.writeln("Nova Linha1");
document.write("Nova Linha2");
document.write("</div>");

var html = document.querySelector("div").innerHTML;
document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = html.replace(/\n/g,"<br>");
```

Comment: Sim, funcionaria desta maneira, mas o writeln deveria ser independente semelhante como outras linguagem de programação o writeln deveria fazer sentido por si só não depender de outro elemento para poder funcionar, assim não teria a necessidade de usá-lo e sim outro elemento ?.

Answer (score 1):

`document.writeln` escreve em uma nova linha. Escreve em uma nova linha no HTML.

Se você verificar o DOM da sua página após executar os comandos, ele irá estar dessa forma:

```html
<body>
    Mesma Linha1Mesma Linha2<br>
    Nova Linha1
    Nova Linha2
</body>
```

Porém você não consegue visualizar essa quebra de linha na sua página, pois HTML ignora quebra de linhas - tanto é que você provavelmente irá usar quebra de linhas no HTML para manter seu código organizado, sem que isso afete a sua página.

Se quiser que quebra de linhas sejam interpretadas literalmente no HTML, tente colocar seu código dentro da tag `<pre>`

```js
// Usando write
document.write("<pre>");
document.write("Mesma Linha1");
document.write("Mesma Linha2");

// Quebra de linha
document.write("<br/>");

// Usando o writeln
document.writeln("Nova Linha1");
document.writeln("Nova Linha2");
```